# increase session time out in asp.net mvc web aplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, session-timeout

In my web application , i have set session time out for 60 minute in the web.config file inside system.web tag, however it is not working. After 30 minute its session get expired. please look into my code below and help me.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
     <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="CacheOneDay" duration="86400" varyByParam="IFAID" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
<sessionState timeout = "60" mode = "InProc" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: check your global.asax file. If there is a timeout set in there it will override the web.config setting

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways session timeout can be set:

- You can increase the time out value in minutes using the timeout attribute of sessionState element in web.config.
- You can set it in code

  Session["UserId"] = 1234;
  Session.Timeout = 60;
- If you are using forms authentication, check the authentication time out value as well.

You have already checked and applied the first item. You can search for `Session.Timeout` in your solution or if you are using forms authentication check for it's timeout variable.

Comment: where should i write the "Session.Timeout = 60" in my web-config or Code behind?